# Delete element from an array and shift everything down

Tags: java

I am facing an issue deleting an element from an array.It gives me error like `outofBounds` and `java.lang.exception "The string isn't in the array"`, but it is.

```
public void setDeleteItem(String deleteItem) throws Exception{
    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {        
        if(deleteItem.equals(array[i])) {   
            array[i] = "";
            if(i < arraySize - 1) {
                array[i] = array[i + 1];
                arraySize--;
            }
        } else if(!deleteItem.equals(array[i])) {
            throw new Exception("This string isn't in the array");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code can only work if the item is the first one... otherwise you enter the `else`. There are other problems here.

Comment: could you give me guidance as to how to fix this

Comment: You have to iterate through the entire array (you can break out if you find it) before you can determine if the element exists. Right now, if the check on the first iteration does not evaluate to true, you throw the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You're throwing exception for every non-match. First iterate through all elements in the array and then decide on exception.

```
public void setItem(String deleteItem) throws{
boolean match = false;
for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {        
    if(delete.equals(array[i])) {
        match = true;   
        array[i] = "";
        if(i < arraySize - 1) {
            array[i + 1] = array[i] ;
            arraySize--;
        }
    } 
}
if(!match){
    throw new Exception("This str in the array");
}
```

Comment: It would be simpler to return in the outer if block and throw after the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Java arrays have a fixed length, storing the length as a separate variable is thus pointless (you don't need it). First, search the array for the element; if it isn't found throw an exception. Otherwise, build a new array - copy the values, and assign the array to your local field. Like,

```
public void setDeleteItem(String deleteItem) throws Exception {
    int p = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (deleteItem.equals(array[i])) {
            p = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (p == -1) {
        throw new Exception("This string isn't in the array");
    }
    String[] newArray = new String[array.length - 1];
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, newArray, 0, p);
    System.arraycopy(array, p + 1, newArray, p, newArray.length - p);
    array = newArray;
}
```

**or** use a `List` (specifically, an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)) - which provides this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You are throwing exception on each match instead you should check entire array and then throw the error. 
You can use following solution for same purpose:
package implementation;

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DeleteFromArray {

public static void delete(String[] array, String deleteItem) throws Exception {
    boolean flag = true;
    int i = 0;
    while (flag && (i < array.length)) {
        if (deleteItem.equals(array[i])) {
            flag = false;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }

    if (!flag) {
        // once item found shift other items
        while (i < array.length - 1) {
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
            i++;
        }
        // copy array to new array
        String[] array1 = new String[array.length - 1];
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, array1, 0, array.length - 1);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));
    } else {
        throw new Exception("This string isn't in the array");
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] array = new String[] { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
    String deleteItem = "five";
    delete(array, deleteItem);
}

}
```